# Select dropdown value from variable

Tags: php, html, html-select

I wanted to have a dropdown's selected value be determined by the results of the a query. But whatever I try, its selected value stays at the very first option.

I've browsed multiple questions with the same problem, but none solved my problem.

I've tried this:

```
<select name="Period">
    <option value="Day" <?php if($PeriodTXT == "Day") echo "selected"?>>Day</option>
    <option value="Week" <?php if($PeriodTXT == "Week") echo "selected"?>>Week</option>
    <option value="Month" <?php if($PeriodTXT == "Month") echo "selected"?>>Month</option>
    <option value="Year" <?php if($PeriodTXT == "Year") echo "selected"?>>Year</option>
</select>
```

And this:

```
<select name="Period">
       <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT == 'Day')?"selected":"" ?> >Day</option>
       <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT == 'Week')?"selected":"" ?> >Week</option>
       <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT == 'Month')?"selected":"" ?> >Month</option>
       <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT == 'Year')?"selected":"" ?> >Year</option>
 </select>
```

But it won't work. Also when I use `echo "$PeriodTXT";` it echos "Week" (exactly as written in the options of the dropdown), so it should've selected "Week" but it doesn't.

EDIT: `$PeriodTXT` is supposed to show the selected interval that came with a number count (example "3 Day" it would only keep the "Day" part)

```
    $usersdata = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $usersdata = $row;
    }

    $PeriodTXT = preg_replace("/\d+/u", "", $usersdata[4]);
```

Comment: Neither approach worked because you have an HTML syntax error: The attribute should be `selected="selected"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem was extra whitespace around the text while you were removing **count** with regex, so hidden extra *whitespace* was yielding condition as false,

```
$PeriodTXT = '3 Week';
$PeriodTXT = preg_replace("/\d+/u", "", $usersdata[4]); //without trim()
var_dump($PeriodTXT); // outputs string ' Week' (length=5)
```

but when we `trim` it

```
$PeriodTXT = trim(preg_replace("/\d+/u", "", $usersdata[4])); //with trim()
var_dump($PeriodTXT); // outputs string 'Week' (length=4)
```

So use `trim()` to fix that, working eg,

```
<?php 
    $usersdata = array();
    $usersdata[4] = '3 Week';
    $PeriodTXT = trim(preg_replace("/\d+/u", "", $usersdata[4]));

?>
    <select name="Period">
           <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT === 'Day')?"selected ='selected'":"" ?> >Day</option>
           <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT === 'Week')?"selected ='selected'":"" ?> >Week</option>
           <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT === 'Month')?"selected ='selected'":"" ?> >Month</option>
           <option <?php echo ($PeriodTXT === 'Year')?"selected ='selected'":"" ?> >Year</option>
     </select>
```

Also notice I have changed the HTML part from `"selected":""` to  `"selected ='selected'":""`

Comment: I think your answer may work because of the selected="selected" - it sounds like from the question that it was already returning "Week" without the whitespace but I think the key maybe your change of selected string.

Comment: This worked, strange since ad @Ukuser32 said "Week" was already without the whitespace. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Yep but while I was var_dump 'ing it it showed me output with whitespaces , anyways it worked now & I am glad

Answer (score 0):

I understand you send a form using POST method, and after you send it, you would like to try display it with the selected option.

Please describe what is `$PeriodTXT` variable and how do you set it up.

Here is a solution to make it easy, hope it will help you.

```
$sent = $_POST['Period'];
$options = aray("Day", "Week", "Month", "Year");


echo '<form method="post" action="">
<select name="Period">';

foreach ($options as $v)
{
  $selected = ($sent == $v) ? ' selected' : null;
  echo '<option value="'.$v.'"'.$selected.'>'.$v.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>';
```

EDIT:

Code with "while" you have posted, seems to be wrong.

You are creating `$userdata` variable each time when while() goes. In fact it's not a real array, as you want it to be. It only works, when you select only one record from database (when `mysql_num_rows($result) == 1`). Otherwise it' wrong.

It should be done this way:

```
$usersdata = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $usersdata[] = $row;
}

$PeriodTXT = preg_replace("/\d+/u", "", $usersdata[$index][4]);
```

Notice, that you have to know which row (`$index` variable) you are doing changes in.

`$usersdata` becomes an [Associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

Use `var_dump()` function to check what a variable contains itself. I hope it will get you closer to the solution. If you need more help, you have to post more code, because for now not everything is clear here.

Comment: I've updated the OP. And no I'm not sending a form to display it from the selected option.

Comment: Your changes in the while loop changed nothing for me, and so far the original while loop worked.